# Validation framework advantages in struts2

Tags: validation, struts2

What will be the advantages of the Validation framework in struts2.

Will it be validate the form on the client side or the server side.

Please give me the suggestion on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first advantage that comes to my mind is that it executes as an interceptor, so validation logic is separated from actual action(You must be aware that interceptors are called before/after action).This makes the logic clean i.e. populate the data in separate logic, validate in different and perform  business logic in a separate one.

Struts2 validation could be done on both server side or client side. You have choice to use  xml, annotation or manual validation. [This link](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html) is a good place to start learning

For a more detailed discussion [look here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/validation.html)

Following are some basic examples

- [xml based](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2validation.shtml)
- [Annotation based](http://java-x.blogspot.com/2008/04/struts-2-validation-annotations.html)
- [Client side](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts-2-client-side-validation-example.shtml)